# Creating a SQL Script that inserts several items into a table but checking if each exist first

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

In SQL Server Management Studio I went to Generate Scripts and create an INSERT script which looks like the following:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Product] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Product] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (1, N'Product 1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Product] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (2, N'Product 2')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Product] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (3, N'Product 3')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Product] OFF
GO
```

Lets say I have multiple client databases and I want to be able to safely run this script on all of them whether these products already exist or not. Do I really have to wrap every single insert line with an if exists or is there a better way?

The ultimate plan is to use it as a Post-Deployment script in a SQL SERVER Database Project for tables that hold items like System Settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not do all the inserts in one step?

```
INSERT [dbo].[Product] ([Id], [Name])
    SELECT id, name
    FROM (VALUES (1, N'Product 1'),
                 (2, N'Product 2')
                 (3, N'Product 3')
         ) v(Id, Name)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Product P2 WHERE p2.id = v.id);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Product] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Product] ([Id], [Name]) 
select id,name from products t where not exists(select 1 from products t2 where t2.id=t1.id and t2.name=t1.name
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Product] OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

A pattern that I've followed recently, which might fit in your situation as well:

```
SELECT name
INTO #My_Table
FROM dbo.My_Table
WHERE 1=0

INSERT INTO #My_Table
VALUES
    ('One'),
    ('Two')
    ... etc.

INSERT INTO dbo.My_Table (id, name)
SELECT id, name
FROM #My_Table
WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM My_Table)

DROP TABLE #My_Table
```

This assumes that `id` is just an `IDENTITY` column and that `name` is the true identifier with a `UNIQUE` constraint on it. If your structure is different then you can adjust accordingly.

If the uniqueness of the row is determined by more than one column then you can use an alternative method to check for existence (`LEFT OUTER JOIN` and check for `NULL` or a subquery, etc.)

I find that this lets me keep all of the data in the table in a convenient, easily readable format that's easy to maintain in the `VALUES`.